# How to skip coloring inf values?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, pandas-styles

I'm styling some data in excel after processing in pandas. But I have some bad data that gives me lot of inf values. Is there a way to skip coloring inf values?

```
        cr = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
        styler = data.style
        zeleno = styler.background_gradient(
            cmap=cr,
            subset=data.columns.get_loc_level('value1', level=1)[0]
        )
        styler.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
```

I got data like this.
[image]

I need to be like this, (skip inf values, they can be white or some other colors)
[image]

Comment: Maybe `cr.set_bad('none')`? That would change the color for "bad" values.

Comment: Not working, still same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is still a better approach to use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) and implement this manually as, even with the addition of `gmap` in 1.3.0, [Styler.background_gradient](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.background_gradient.html#pandas-io-formats-style-styler-background-gradient) cannot support separate Data manipulation and display as well as subsetting.

---

To make this work we need to accomplish 2 things:

1. [`set_bad`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_bad) to establish how to handle the "bad" values
2. Make sure that `inf` are considered to be "bad" (which they are not)

The easiest way to ensure that `inf` are considered bad is to [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) `inf` with `NaN`.

```
# Subset The DataFrame Before-Hand
cr = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
# Set Bad to something like White
cr.set_bad('white')


def my_gradient(s, cmap):
    return [f'background-color: {mcolors.rgb2hex(x)}'
            for x in cmap(s.replace(np.inf, np.nan))]


# Use Subset Styler
styler = data.style
zeleno = styler.apply(
    my_gradient,
    cmap=cr,  # Passed to function
    subset=data.columns.get_loc_level('value1', level=1)[0],
    axis=0  # (Default)
)
zeleno
```

[image: styled table gradient with inf as white]

*Styling only applied to subset (`value1` on level=1)

---

Setup and Imports Used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  # version 1.3.3
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors

np.random.seed(25)
a = np.random.random((3, 4))
# Replace Randomly With inf
a[np.random.randint(0, 2, size=a.shape) == 0] = np.inf

data = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
    list('AB'),
    ['value1', 'value2']
]))
data
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: Can I use similar way to solve this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69400814/how-to-color-strings-with-seaborn

Comment: Could also use `background_gradient` with a `vmax` and then separately use another highlight function afterwards to specifically target `inf`.