# How to color strings with seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a data of strings (letters) in excel file and I'm looking a way to show it more visual atractive.

I like seaborn coloring cells, I was wondering can I do that. I have 6 values, (a,b,c,d,e,f).

Like this and to be part of gradient of same color.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use continuous colors for discrete values as it. You have to pick colors along the palette. Create a dict of unique letters as key and color as value.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

data = {'data1': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'a', 'e'],
        'data2': ['c', 'd', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'f', 'd'],
        'data3': ['a', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'c', 'a']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

values = np.unique(np.ravel(df)).tolist()
colors = dict(zip(values, sns.color_palette('flare', len(values)).as_hex()))

df.style.applymap(lambda v: f"background-color: {colors[v]}; color: white") \
        .to_excel('data.xlsx')
```

[image: background-color]

**Update**

> Is it possible to restrict for just two columns, like `data1` and `data3`?

```
def highlight_column(col):
    if col.name in ['data1', 'data3']:
        return [f"background-color: {colors[v]}; color: white" for v in col.values]

df.style.apply(highlight_column).to_excel('data.xlsx')
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to read that and thanks for your support :) +1 for you too

Comment: One sub-question, is it possible to restrict for just two columns, like `data1` and `data3`?

Comment: @project.py. I updated my answer.

Comment: I got this error, `ValueError: Function <function OnlyKAT.<locals>.highlight_column at 0x7f1bf0ecc430> returned the wrong shape.
Result has shape: (17,)
Expected shape:   (24, 17)`. I think this happens because I have my data on level=1.

Comment: You have a multiindex for columns?

Comment: Yes, but never mind, you answered what I asked.